# Twitter OAuth on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, oauth

I need to register on our server via twitter. I made registration with help of OAuth. When we make any request on our server we check our token is active, if our token is expired we make resign on our server and I need to resign in Twitter session, I do logout, but session is active.  Android team do it with help

```
TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
TwitterCore.getInstance().logOut();
```

. How can I do it on iOS? I use Swift Please, help me.

My code

```
func auth(userEmail: String?, successLoginCallback: ((usr : User) -> Void)?, failLoginCallback: ( (message: String) -> Void )?) {
    Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.reloadSessionStore()
    Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey(twitterKey, consumerSecret: twitterSecret)
    Twitter.sharedInstance().logInWithCompletion { (session, error) in
        if session != nil {
            TWTRAPIClient.clientWithCurrentUser().requestEmailForCurrentUser({ (twitterEmail, error) in
                // oauth parameters
                let oauthSession = TWTRSession(authToken: session!.authToken, authTokenSecret: session!.authTokenSecret, userName: session!.userName, userID: session!.userID)

                let oauthSigning = TWTROAuthSigning(authConfig: Twitter.sharedInstance().authConfig, authSession: oauthSession)
                let headers = oauthSigning.OAuthEchoHeadersToVerifyCredentials()
                guard let authHeaders = headers as? [String : AnyObject] else {
                    return
                }
                var passEmail: String?
                if userEmail != nil {
                    passEmail = userEmail
                }
                UserManager.sharedManager.logInViaTwitter(passEmail, parameters: authHeaders, success: { (user) in
                    self.userIsLogginedViaTwitter = true
                    self.twitterSuccessLogin(user)
                    print("user token", user.token?.expr)
                    successLoginCallback?(usr: user)
                    }, fail: { (errorMessage) in
                        if errorMessage != nil {
                            self.twitterFailsLogin(errorMessage!)
                            failLoginCallback?(message: errorMessage!)
                        }
                })
            })
        }
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

 func logOut(success: (() -> ())?) {
        Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey(twitterKey, consumerSecret: twitterSecret)
        guard let userID = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID else { return }
        Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.logOutUserID(userID)
        userIsLogginedViaTwitter = false
        let cookieStorage: NSHTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
        cookieStorage.cookies?.forEach({ (cook) in
            cookieStorage.deleteCookie(cook)
        })
        success?()
    }



 // MARK: - Twitter functions 
    func logInViaTwitter(email: String?, parameters: [String : AnyObject], success: ((user: User) -> ())?, fail: ((errorMessage: String?) -> ())?) {
        let url = "\(Networking.baseUrl)/auth/login/tw"
        guard let oauth_url = parameters["X-Auth-Service-Provider"] as? String else { return }
        guard let oauth_params = parameters["X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization"] as? String else { return }
        var passParameters = [String : AnyObject]()
        if email != nil {
            passParameters = ["email" : email!, "oauth_url" : oauth_url, "oauth_params": oauth_params]
        } else {
            passParameters = ["oauth_url" : oauth_url, "oauth_params": oauth_params]
        }
        print("Twitter manager passParameters", passParameters, "Twitter manager passParameters")

        Networking.manager.request(.POST, url, parameters: passParameters, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil).responseObject { (response: Response<RegisterResponse, NSError>) in
            guard let result = response.result.value else {
                fail?(errorMessage: nil)
                return
            }

            if result.meta?.errors.count == 0 {
                print(result.response)
                guard let user = Mapper<User>().map(result.response) else {
                    fail?(errorMessage: nil)
                    return
                }
                // Save state in Twitter manager
                TwitterManager.sharedManager.userIsLogginedViaTwitter = true
                self.saveCurrentUser(user)
                success?(user: user)
            } else {
                fail?(errorMessage: result.meta?.errors.first?.message)
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have changed the query logic, so that with every request we did not request information from the Twitter framework.